# Why can't I get the Songs package index to generate in Overleaf?

Tags: indexing, overleaf, songs

So I know people have asked similar questions and the answer has been "run commands in a terminal", but I've only ever used latex in overleaf, so I don't know what that means. And also I feel like maybe it should all work within overleaf?

Anyway I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic} %SEE, it works ;)

\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.8cm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0pt}{0pt}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\indexsongsas{titleidx}{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\idxtitlefont}{\sffamily\normalfont}

\begin{document}

%\showindex[2]{Contents}{mainindex}
\showindex{Title index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{England}[by = {Séan McCann}]
\index{England}
\capo{2}
\beginchorus
We were \[G]far from the \[C]shores of \[D]Eng\[G]land
\[G]Far from our \[C]children and \[D]wives
To \[C]play our \[G]hand in the \[D]Newfound\[G]land
Where the \[G]wind cuts \[C]like a \[D]knife
We were \[G]far from the \[C]shores of \[D]Eng\[G]land
\endchorus 
 
\beginverse 
We \[G]shipped on board the \[D]Mary\[G]anne
To \[G]find a \[C]better \[D]life
And we \[C]walked a\[G]cross the \[D]wa\[G]ter 
When she \[G]broke up \[C]on the \[D]ice
We \[G]came ashore in \[D]Carbon\[G]ear 
With \[G]nothing \[C]but our \[D]rights
And I \[C]wondered \[G]if I \[D]e'er a\[G]gain
Would \[G]see my \[C]London \[D]lights 
\endverse 

\beginchorus
Chorus
\endchorus

\beginverse 
We spent our days amid the waves
Working water, hook and twine
We would go for weeks with blistered cheeks
Waiting for the sun to shine
But as long as the sky hold over us
We will not taste the brine
And we'll curse the cod with the fear of God
As we haul in every line
\endverse 

\beginchorus 
We were far from the shores of England
Far from our children and wives
To play our hand in the Newfoundland
Where the wind cuts like a knife
We were \[G]far from the \[C]shores of \[D]Eng\[G]land
\[G]Far from our \[C]native \[D]soil
To \[C]chase a \[G]wish and to \[D]hunt the \[G]fish
And \[G]on the \[C]rocks to \[D]toil
We were far from the shores of England
\endchorus 

\beginverse 
Should we find Fortune's Favour
And be spared from the gale
We will live off honest labour
With our hearts as big as sails
But if I should die don't bury me
Or leave me to the sea
Please send my bones back to my home
Where my spirit can be free
\endverse 

\beginchorus 
We were far from the shores of England
Far from our children and wives
To play our hand in the Newfoundland
Where the wind cuts like a knife
We were far from the shores of England
Far from our native soil
To chase a wish and hunt the Fish
And on the rocks to toil
We were far from the shores of England
\endchorus
\endsong 

\beginsong{Grace}[by = {Sean And Frank O'Meara}]
\capo{3}
\beginverse 
As we \[D]gather in the chapel here in \[G]old Kilmainham \[A]jail
I \[G]think about these \[D]last few weeks, oh \[Em]will they say we \[A]failed
From our \[D]school days they have told us we must \[G]yearn for liber\[A]ty
Yet \[G]all I want in \[D]this dark place is to \[A]have you here with \[D]me
\endverse 
 
\beginchorus
Oh \[A]Grace, just hold me in your arms and \[G]let this moment \[D]linger
They \[G]take me out at \[D]dawn and I will \[A]die
With all my love I place this wedding \[G]ring upon your \[D]finger
There \[G]won't be time to \[D]share our love so \[A]we must say good\[D]bye
\endchorus 

\beginverse 
Now I know it's hard for you my love to ever understand
The love I bear for these brave men, the love for this dear land
But when Pádraig called me to his side down in the GPO
I had to leave my own sick bed, to him I had to go
\endverse 

\beginchorus
Chorus
\endchorus

\beginverse 
Now as the dawn is breaking, my heart is breaking too
On this May morn as I walk out, my thoughts will be of you
And I'll write some words upon the wall so everyone will know
I loved so much that I could see his blood upon the rose
\endverse 

\beginchorus
Chorus
\endchorus
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

And the first page just looks like this:

[image: Title index not yet generated]

Any pro tips?

Comment: You give no indication of the problem you had. [I tried your example on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pcyrhhthwqnv) and got the same output that you show, with the same warnings about bad page layout as getting when running it locally.

Comment: Given that there is no content in your document, what output are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, should've included a song or two in the example. I left them out for the sake of convenience. I'll add a couple in, but it seems like maybe it wants me to run something separate to generate this index?

Comment: Reading the `songs` manual you need to tell overleaf to also run `texlua songidx.lua cbtitle.sxd cbtitle.sbx` in order to generate the index, this is not automatic, see section 10.3 in the `songs` manual. As I'm not an overleaf user, I have no idea how to get overleaf/latexmk to run this when needed.